# Order after asymptotic growth

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have to order this list as an asymptotic growth. This is what I came up with so far.

But I'm unsure with log(2^n) where to place it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

so log(2^n) = n*log(2) = n * const

and **const > 1** (log(2)) so its equivalent to O(n)

```
1^n < 3log2(2) < 8sqrt(n) < log(2^n) < n^(4/2) < 7n^3
```